# Alhpa/Beta Testing use 30 featured days?

Tags: android, google-play-games, google-play

We have a very important question regarding our Android App.
So we created an app in the developer console, filled the Store Details, 
uploaded an **APK to BETA** (not production) and filled the prices.

We had to click on "**publish now**" on our beta tab so that testers could download it.
It was all pretty scary because we dont want our app to be able for downloading, only in our google groups. The "publish now" button now says "**Published**".

Our question is:

Google play grants new app 30 days visibility in the **"Top New Free/Paid"** categories which hugely boosts your downloads, giving you a better start,

Since we hit publish, (only with a beta version uploaded, no production listed),
**do the 30 days granted by google play start counting?** or they only count from the moment you upload a production version / promote the beta to production?

Comment: DO you got any answer for this? i do have same doubt

Comment: No sir. But im going to rename packages and create a new apk proyect when beta is completed, just in case.

Comment: let clear it with someone who knows better :hug: since had prepared my other app with package name , and i messed up my console already with another apk published accidently, i want this time work well.. i will let you know if i got anything :hug: thanks

Comment: please do, thank you! 2x:hug:

Comment: contacted them yesterday, and they provided me link for it, please look at the answer,nothing need to worry,If my answer is helpful please tick my Answer :hug:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Contacted Google and they provided me link and explanation :**
"Top New app lists look at the publishing date of the first production APK when considering what is less than 30 days old. The time in which an app is in Alpha or Beta has no effect on its first production date and its ability to be in any Top New list."

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/1295940?hl=en

You dont have to upload a new apk,Just change the status from beta to production, Go with confidence and hit the Top list , good luck :hug:

Comment: On publish console, on top right corner there is a small button with a question mark sign, click it and there you can see an option to contact them. its the easiest and fast way, i usually get reply with in 24 hours. but i think its automated, sometimes not useful :hug: